# Centered image map bigger than portrait mode in mobile. How to fix?

Tags: css, image, html, mobile, center

So I just made a very simple website where an image is dead centre on the page. It's actually an image map.
The issue that I'm having is that on mobile it's wider than the phone in portrait mode.
How can I make it so the image is contained within the screen on mobile?

Here's the link:
[www.thelastdescendantfilm.com](http://thelastdescendantfilm.com)

And here's the code:

```
    body {
    background-color: #000000;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #000;
}


a img { 
    border: none;
}

img.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#horizon        
    {
    color: white;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    overflow: visible;
    visibility: visible;
    display: block
    }

#content    
    {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: transparent;
    margin-left: -564px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -254px;
    left: 50%;
    width: 1129px;
    height: 508px;
    visibility: visible
    }

.map_image { display: block; width: 1129px; height: 508px; position: relative; background-position: 0 0; background-repeat: no-repeat; }
.map_image .map_link { display: block; position: absolute; text-indent: -999em; overflow: hidden; }
.map_image #map_link_0 { width: 434px; height: 56px; top: 390px; left: 662px; }
.map_image #map_link_1 { width: 261px; height: 48px; top: 453px; left: 836px; }

</style></head>

<body>

<div id="horizon">
    <div id="content">
    <div class="map_image" style="background-image: url('tldmain.jpg');">
    <a class="map_link" id="map_link_0" title="" href="http://igg.me/p/the-last-descendant/x/6785523">Join Us</a>
    <a class="map_link" id="map_link_1" title="" href="http://www.facebook.com/thelastdescendant">Follow Us</a>
    </div>
    </div>
  <!-- end .container --></div>
</body>
```

Comment: `background-size: 50% 50%` may work.

Comment: in which div should I put that?

Comment: I guess no one knows? I just don't know what to modify and where. I don't mind doing the research but there's so many factors here - like divs inside divs and the image being a background of a map... I just don't know what to do lol